# NodeJS - wrong line number in error stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stack-trace

can someone explain (or better provide the solution) why I have wrong numbers in my error stack trace when I use **async** function?

```
class AsyncTest {
    async foo() {
        try {
            throw new Error("error msg1") // wrong stack trace
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
const test = new AsyncTest();
test.foo()

----------

Error: error msg1
    at AsyncTest.<anonymous> (...path\dist\app.js:15:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at ...path\dist\app.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (...path\dist\app.js:4:12)
    at AsyncTest.foo (...path\dist\app.js:13:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...path\dist\app.js:24:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
```

This is my builded file in ...path\dist\app.js

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
class AsyncTest {
    foo() {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            try {
                throw new Error("error msg1");
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
const test = new AsyncTest();
test.foo();
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiYXBwLmpzIiwic291cmNlUm9vdCI6IiIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsiLi4vYXBwLnRzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiI7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7QUFBQSxNQUFNLFNBQVM7SUFDTCxHQUFHOztZQUNMLElBQUk7Z0JBQ0EsTUFBTSxJQUFJLEtBQUssQ0FBQyxZQUFZLENBQUMsQ0FBQTthQUNoQztZQUFDLE9BQU0sQ0FBQyxFQUFFO2dCQUNQLE9BQU8sQ0FBQyxHQUFHLENBQUMsQ0FBQyxDQUFDLENBQUE7YUFDakI7UUFDTCxDQUFDO0tBQUE7Q0FDSjtBQUVELE1BQU0sSUFBSSxHQUFHLElBQUksU0FBUyxFQUFFLENBQUM7QUFFN0IsSUFBSSxDQUFDLEdBQUcsRUFBRSxDQUFBIn0=
```

I see that in this file is variable __awaiter, which moves the whole code a few lines lower. But how to have correct stack trace? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run nodejs with source map support enabled.
A library that does exactly this is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support

Just install it and import it like this:

```js
import 'source-map-support/register'
```

And you should start seeing the correct line numbers in your stack trace.